# How can I count value changes based on 2 other columns?

Tags: python, pandas, counter

I have the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [{'testid': 'testid_1', 'value':15},
{'testid': 'testid_1', 'value':15},
{'testid': 'testid_1', 'value':20},
{'testid': 'testid_1', 'value':20},
{'testid': 'testid_1', 'value':15},
{'testid': 'testid_1', 'value':15},
{'testid': 'testid_2', 'value':215},
{'testid': 'testid_2', 'value':215},
{'testid': 'testid_3', 'value':215},
{'testid': 'testid_3', 'value':69},
{'testid': 'testid_3', 'value':215}]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df
Out[5]: 
      testid  value
0   testid_1     15
1   testid_1     15
2   testid_1     20
3   testid_1     20
4   testid_1     15
5   testid_1     15
6   testid_2    215
7   testid_2    215
8   testid_3    215
9   testid_3     69
10  testid_3    215
```

What I've been looking for is to create a column named `counter` or something like it, that tracks the changes numerically of the columns `testid` and `values`.

Everytime that `testid` changes the counter should be reseted to `1`, remaining the same while `values` don't change, and if change add `1`.

Here is my desired output:

```
      testid  value  counter
0   testid_1     15        1
1   testid_1     15        1
2   testid_1     20        2
3   testid_1     20        2
4   testid_1     15        3
5   testid_1     15        3
6   testid_2    215        1
7   testid_2    215        1
8   testid_3    215        1
9   testid_3     69        2
10  testid_3    215        3
```

Notice that independently of `value` if the `testid` changes, the counter return to `1`.

I've been trying using `shift()` and stuff to compare but my main problem has been to track the counter according to the changes

Thanks very munch I'll appreciate the help

Answer (score 0):

In your case

```
df['newid']=df.groupby('testid').value.apply(lambda x : x.diff().ne(0).cumsum())
```